# Forecasts are at a different level to base in hts/combinef forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am forecasting a multi-level hierarchy of smoothed series using the hts forecasting package. Some series have forecasts at significantly different levels to the input series.

As pictured below, the issue is worst with OLS, followed by WLS and resolved using MinT. What is the cause of this?

[image]

Further, the MinT method requires a positive definite covariance matrix which my data does not produce – any advice on how to force this would be appreciated. Although it appears to be an existing issue on [github](https://github.com/earowang/hts/issues/43).

The example code is as follows:

```
library(hts)
library(forecast)
i <- structure(c(106.9854167, 107.4867489, 107.96789, 108.4267171, 
                 108.861098, 109.2706768, 109.6582435, 110.0287576, 110.3869454, 
                 110.7345808, 111.0690715, 111.3851015, 111.677639, 111.9431968, 
                 112.1789404, 112.3821822, 112.5508856, 112.6834374, 112.778066, 
                 112.8327908, 112.8450649, 112.8126924, 112.737467, 112.626777, 
                 112.491261, 112.3414448, 112.1848447, 112.025069, 111.8621304, 
                 111.6930745, 111.5133322, 111.3184901, 111.1059717, 110.8760311, 
                 110.6320535, 110.3798403, 110.1262628, 109.8782884, 109.6426699, 
                 109.424362, 109.2250421, 109.0436044, 108.8777843, 108.7262946, 
                 108.5898513, 108.4715309, 108.376186, 108.30899, 108.2751504, 
                 108.2802032, 108.3293916, 108.425466, 108.5675223, 108.7522261, 
                 108.974478, 109.2284484, 109.5089229, 109.8108365, 110.1282988, 
                 110.4545046, 110.7819276, 111.1024134, 111.4078923, 111.691544, 
                 111.9491555, 112.1790872, 112.3799224, 112.5493353, 112.6844073, 
                 112.7832648, 112.8487456, 112.8879805, 112.9086545, 112.9165471, 
                 112.9142819, 112.9027337, 488.1267175, 491.6515351, 495.1732907, 
                 498.6682018, 502.1109109, 505.4768101, 508.7461967, 511.9075758, 
                 514.9577698, 517.9010825, 520.7501287, 523.5269338, 526.2608893, 
                 528.9812343, 531.7101381, 534.4620338, 537.2453605, 540.0646112, 
                 542.9226093, 545.8223307, 548.7658024, 551.7503117, 554.7685435, 
                 557.8146846, 560.8904865, 564.0079654, 567.1882539, 570.4545144, 
                 573.8221354, 577.2957925, 580.8732898, 584.5496138, 588.3198042, 
                 592.179817, 596.1244182, 600.1437264, 604.2229377, 608.345213, 
                 612.4933253, 616.6490661, 620.7926085, 624.9059139, 628.9774089, 
                 633.0002338, 636.9678027, 640.8707663, 644.6971958, 648.4407796, 
                 652.1082035, 655.7176816, 659.294086, 662.8625666, 666.4433905, 
                 670.0538744, 673.7136875, 677.4477938, 681.2874351, 685.2680251, 
                 689.4219773, 693.7712197, 698.3241234, 703.0769519, 708.0191579, 
                 713.1410688, 718.4380144, 723.9059919, 729.535861, 735.3133214, 
                 741.2216286, 747.2419478, 753.3494854, 759.5122156, 765.6978613, 
                 771.8827379, 778.0532199, 784.198938), .Dim = c(76L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
                   NULL, c("H44", "H45")), .Tsp = c(21, 96, 1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
i_hts <- hts(i , characters = c(1, 2))
comb_i_hts_ols <- forecast(i_hts
                           , h=5
                           , method = "comb"
                           , weights = "ols"
                           , fmethod = "arima")
comb_ols<-as.ts(rbind(comb_i_hts_ols$histy,comb_i_hts_ols$bts))
comb_i_hts_wls <- forecast(i_hts
                           , h=5
                           , method = "comb"
                           , weights = "wls"
                           , fmethod = "arima")
comb_wls<-as.ts(rbind(comb_i_hts_wls$histy,comb_i_hts_wls$bts))
comb_i_hts_mint <- forecast(i_hts
                       , h=5
                       , method = "comb"
                       , weights = "mint", covariance = "shr"
                       , fmethod = "arima")
comb_mint<-as.ts(rbind(comb_i_hts_mint$histy,comb_i_hts_mint$bts))

plot_set <- cbind(comb_mint[,1],comb_ols[,1],comb_wls[,1])
plot(plot_set)
```